# Creating point fill that exceeds polygon boundary in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, symbology, fill

My question starts off here: [Creating random point polygon fill symbology in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236413/creating-random-point-polygon-fill-symbology-in-qgis)

In addition to the random point pattern fill of a polygon, I want my points not to be clipped by the polygon boundary. How do I go about that?

Currently, my layout looks like this:

[image]

I want the trees to exceed the outer boundary like they would in real life.

I've seen this script here (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/337774/200736), which seems to be a starting point but my understanding of the syntax is too poor to see where I exactly I would need to make the necessary changes.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: is there a limit to how far they go? if so a buffer could help

Comment: There is no definite limit - about 5-10m on scale would be appropriate I think. I thought about the buffer but since it is just a point pattern fill (i.e., I did not map every single tree), I do not see how a buffer would help (maybe i'm just not getting it right now). In my understanding it would still lead to my trees being cut off at some point. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it myself (at least sufficiently for me):

I added a symbol layer to my polygon and changed it to 'Marker Line'. Then I changed the Marker to 'SVG Marker' with a size of 8 Meters at scale and chose my tree symbol. In the 'Marker Line' section 'Marker placement', I activated a data defined override and changed the interval with the following expression:

`randf(3, 8)` - for a random interval between 3 and 8 map units (in my case, meters).

Looks like this now:

[image]

Of course, I could still optimize the randomization and also randomize the size of my outline tree symbols.